# jquery target input value inside divs with class checked

Tags: php, jquery, class, html, get

I am foreaching a number of suppliers in a quotation form, each with a checkbox element to tick which should be contacted. suppliers are in divs with class names supplier-checkbox, moreover upon selecting supplier the supplier-checkbox div gets appended with "checkedsupplier" or "uncheckedsupplier" class name.

```
<div class="supplier-checkbox checkedsupplier">

<input type="hidden" name="supplier-email" class="supplieremail" value="{$item->email}" />
                                    </div> <!--end supplier checkbox-->
```

foreach supplier div I get a hidden input field within the div holding the supplier email as its value. idea is that upon submitting form I'd check for all div's with "checkedsupplier" class name and for each obtain the value of the input inside of it, hold all values in onelong variable and echo it into the To field of the email to replicate the quotation form to each supplier.

using jquery, I managed to toggle the class name and a background effect showing ticked or unticked with the below.

```
<script> 
    $(".supplier-checkbox").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('checkedsupplier uncheckedsupplier')
    //$(this).children( ".supplieremail" ).attr("checked")
});
</script>
```

can anyone give me any pointers on how to foreach by class name and fetch value of each input inside every div with that class name using jquery. Im working on it and yet found the .each for looping .val for values and if (bar) for conditional. but am not yet experienced enough to put things together. have been working as a junior developer for 7 months now since graduating in networking which is a completely different field.

in the app.js file I'm obtaining the form values this way: 
`

```
v_country:$('#country').val(),
v_quotationtel:$('#quotationtel').val(),
                v_mobile:$('#mobile').val(),
                v_quotationemail:$('#quotationemail').val(),
                v_quotemefor:$('#quotemefor').val(),
    v_quotemessage:$('#quotemessage').val()
                //this line is what i'm trying to do to get input values and store them in one var to pass them to php form that sends email $( "checksupplier" ).each(function( i ) {

         }`
```

thanks everyone on stack! I believe in you guys here you've all helped me throughout my studies and work.

Ian

** Update ** It's been modified to work as follows:

```
 <script>
        $(function(){
            $( ".crew-member-con" ).click(function(){
                $(this).toggleClass('whitebg greybg');
                $(this).toggleClass('crew-checked crew-unchecked');
                $(this).toggleClass('grey white');
                if($(this).children('input').prop('checked') == true){
                    $(this).children('input').prop('checked', false);
                }else{
                    $(this).children('input').prop('checked', true);
                }

                var selectedMembers='';
                $('.selected-members').each(function(){
                    if($(this).is(':checked')){
                        selectedMembers +=$(this).val()+', ';
                    }
                   //alert(emails);
                });
                if(selectedMembers != ''){
                    selectedMembers = selectedMembers.slice(0,-2);
                }
                $('#exam-member span').html(selectedMembers);
                console.log(selectedMembers);
});         

        });
```

Comment: Use `on('change', function` or `.change(function`, not `.click(function` when listening to a checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script> 
$(".supplier-checkbox").click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('checkedsupplier uncheckedsupplier')
//$(this).children( ".supplieremail" ).attr("checked")
var emails='';
$('.supplieremail').each(function(){
   emails +=$(this).val();
});

$('#mailfieldstextarea').val(emails);
});
</script>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for your feedback mate. I think logically in your suggested solution is that it doesn't differentiate between .supplieremail inputs that have their parent div with class checkedsupplier or unchecked supplier. Since I added an alert after line 7 of your code: alert(emails); and upon clicking a supplier an alert shows the email, automatically it reshows with next supplier email and reiterates populating each suppliers email into the variable without having clicked on any other supplier after the first one. it needs a conditional if to check for the parent div class to have checkedsupplier

Comment: Can you share your all html with parent and child element.

Comment: thanks man for your answer it helped me nail it, thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with some notes.

```
 $('.myform').submit(function () {
    getEmailAddresses();
    return false; 
}

function getEmailAddresses () {
    // a place to hold them
    var emails = new Array();
    // what will be after 'mailto'
    var emailsString = "";

    // get 'em
    $('.checkedsupplier').each(function () {
        // get the hidden email input value
        var email = $(this).find('.supplieremail').val();
        // check, just in case;
        if (email) {
            // push the value into our array
            emails.push(email); 
        }
    });

    //put them all together into a string, split by a semi-colon
    emailsString = emails.join(';');

    // finally, stuff our mail to link. 
    // Not sure what you're plan is here but 'emailsString' has all of the values you eed.
    $('.mailtolink').attr('href', 'mailto:'+emailsString);

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mate! I ended up taking parts of both answers and it worked out beautifully thanks to your contribution! Now it's been modified even a bit further to fit it's purpose better. :) you make other people's sun shine!